# Range of floating-point numbers

Tags: elixir

I'm trying elixir, and this issue came up – I can't seem to be able to create a range of floating-point numbers as boundaries.

As per Dave Thomas's book, page 24:

> Ranges are represented as start..end, where start and end can be any type...

However, when I try to create a range using floating-point numbers, I get an error:

```
iex(1)> 1.1..3.1 
** (ArgumentError) ranges (left .. right) expect both sides to be integers, got: 1.1 .. 3.1
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.../2
             iex:1: (file)
```

I figured there's a work around this:

```
iex(2)> a = 1.1
1.1
iex(3)> b = 3.1
3.1
iex(4)> a..b
1.1..3.1
```

However, in later case, the `in` operator fails to return value I intuitively expect:

```
iex(5)> 2.0 in a..b
false
```

I'm clearly missing something here. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**Update**. Assigning `c = a..b` doesn't resolve the issue:

```
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.1.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> a = 1.1
1.1
iex(2)> b = 3.1
3.1
iex(3)> c = a..b
1.1..3.1
iex(4)> 2.0 in c
false
```

**Update 2**. It seems I can construct a range using `a`, `b`, and `c` as shown above (which is no longer considered a legit?), but [not using macro](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f8a82f604ab96610441c8ef926a7d742d3c3ac24/lib/elixir/test/elixir/range_test.exs#L44-L58), since 1.1.

Which leaves me with this question:

**What is the default opt-in for making a range of floating-point numbers such that I could check if it covers a given number?**

Comment: It works for me (Elixir (1.0.4)) - all versions of your code

Comment: Consider what you're asking for.  The range has an implied step of 1. What happens if you give it a start and end which can't be discretely covered with steps of 1 each?  Warning?  Error?   It also seems that you consider the range should be continuous. I get the impression that in fact it's more of a set of discrete values. That is rather than being a continuous range from s to e it's more like [s,s+1,s+2 . . . e-2, e-1, e].  So even if my range were 1..3 if I ask if 2.5 is in the range it's going to return false. Or to use your example, I'd expect 2.1 in c to be true but not 2.0.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci you're right. I mistakenly treat range as something continuous. I only though so since the name suggests that. If the implementation is not continuous, which I now understand the case – what I need can be achieved by just checking the boundaries manually, e.g. `a < 2.0 & 2.0 < b`

Comment: I guess I always considered ranges that way (discrete not continuous) because that's how they behave in F# and that's where I first ran across the concept.

Comment: A continuous range between floating point numbers would be an infinite sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Elixir 1.0.4, where I am able to checks like `1.2 in a..b`.

Since you are using Elixir 1.1.1, it is possible that Elixir 1.1 added a check that disallows non-integer ranges.

This issue, [Fix ranges to only accept integers as first and last elements](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/3781), provides details.

Comment: Thanks, I just did exactly this (assigning to `c`), and my code returns `false`. I basically just run your code and get `false` instead of `true` on iex(4). Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I realized that...your code works for me without parentheis.

Comment: Thanks, Wand Maker. I dug that too. I made an update to my question and will leave it open, since the initial problem (e.g. how do I create a range of floats such that I could then check if it covers a given number) remains unsolved.

Comment: @gmile As per issue linked to by @WandMaker, the ability construct ranges with floating point boundaries was a bug. It is now fully fixed as of Elixir 1.2.0-rc.0, meaning that ranges only support integers. To check if a floating-point number `x` is in a mathematical range `(a; b)`, you can write `a < x and x < b`.

Comment: It is simply not possible to use ranges for that. You have to write it explicitly as @android mentioned.